# Can innerHTML be dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to append ball on different location every time I click on screen but I can't figure out how to write box.innerHTML.

script:

```
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
var box = document.getElementById("box");

box.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var x = e.clientX -50;
    var y = e.clientY -50;
    box.innerHTML += '<div id="ball" style="left:'x'px;top:'y'px;"></div>';

})
```

css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    #box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: dimgrey;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #ball {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
box.innerHTML += '<div id="ball" style="left:' + x + 'px;top:' + y + 'px;"></div>';
```

To concatenate strings, you need to add a `+` between the string and your variables.

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

`box.innerHTML += '<div id="ball" style="left:' + x + 'px;top:' + y + 'px;"></div>';`

The problem is that your variables x and y are being identified as strings. Using + , you can concatenate them.

For further information I recommend reading about string literals here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not necessary to use a lot of divs with the same id. It is better to define them for the class

```
.ball {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
}    

var box = document.getElementById("box");

box.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var x = e.clientX -50;
    var y = e.clientY -50;

    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.top = y+'px';
    element.style.left = x+'px';
    element.className = "ball";
    box.appendChild(element);
});
```